# How to represent uncertainty on the support of a (uniform) distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

I want to represent a situation where a Bayesian agent believes that a certain quantity is uniformly distributed over an interval $[\underline{X},\overline{X}]$ but is uncertain on the value of $\underline{X}$ and $\overline{X}$. In other words, $\underline{X},\overline{X}$ are random variables and she might receive informative signals about them. In this sense, the agents' uncertainty is double layered, pertaining not only the value of the quantity, but also the distribution it follows.

My problem is how to represent such a situation, in the sense that I consider adopting a Bayesian Hierarchical Model where $\underline{X}\sim\mathcal{N}(\underline{x},1)$, $\overline{X}\sim\mathcal{N}(\overline{x},1)$, but I don't know how to introduce dependency between $\underline{X}$ and $\overline{X}$ so that
$$\mathbb{P}(\underline{X}<\overline{X})=1$$
which is the condition ensuring that $\underline{X}$ and $\overline{X}$ almost surely define an interval.

I thought that random set theory (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/1-84628-150-4) might help here, but, in that field I am even less experienced than in Bayesian statistics.

Any help or reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it just doesn't make sense to ask that the upper and lower bounds of the interval be normally distributed, for exactly this reason. You could try distributing the midpoint $m$ of the interval normally and then using a non-negative distribution for the spread $s$ (e.g. exponential) so that the interval is $[m-s, m+s]$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking (but with two iid exponentials to have "the lowest possible correlation" between the two extremes). The point is that I would like the agent to receive signals on the values of the extremes, and to make computations it would be convenient to have conjugacy. Hence, if I use distributions from the Gamma family, my extremes can only "move in one direction" after updating (the lower to the left and the higher to the right). Am I wrong?